# EditText that looks like a normal web form with blue border during focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, themes

I want to replace the Ice Cream Sandwich EditText with an EditText that looks like a normal web form (a white box).

I want to replace the default EditText that looks like this. This would be a really bad UI design for my application:

[image: Edit Text Design Ice Cream Sandwich]

How can I easily switch to a "normal" EditText design with white enclosing boxes?

Although I still need the **blue border line** when my EditText has focus.

I allready added this to my styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/textfield_default</item>
```

This has the design that I want to achieve, but the problem is that there are no blue border lines when the EditText has focus.

I allready tested the old EditText design (android 1.5 and above), which looks really good, but it has an ugly orange border during focus...

Comment: You want to achieve a bordered white box?

Comment: I want to achieve a blue border whenever the box has focus. I allready tested the old edittext design, but this has an ugly orange border during focus.

Answer (score 0):

first define this line in your EditText xml definition:
android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"

now you have to create a xml file and put in your drawable folder. create edittext_style.xml and put these code inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#0000FF" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I think this does not have the behaviour that I want to achieve. I want the blue border line only when the EditText has focus.